# User Input to set dynamic variable Python

Tags: python, user-input

I made a simple random.choice code by myself. But there is a major problem with it. I can't take user input to dynamically set variables.

```
import pygame
import pygame_menu
import random

kolay_secim = ["agac","odun","baba"]
orta_secim = ["zar","okey","tavla"]
zor_secim = ["emekli","yasli","deli"]
zorluk_secimi=input('Hangi zorlukta oynamak istiyorsunuz? (kolay,orta,zor)')
if zorluk_secimi == kolay :
    print(random.choice(kolay_secim))

elif zorluk_secimi  == orta :
    print(random.choice(orta_secim))

elif zorluk_secimi == zor :
    print(random.choice(zor_secim))

else:
    print("Gecersiz Zorluk Secimi yazima dikkat ediniz.")
```

What I'm trying to achieve is taking a user input and setting that as zorluk_secimi and after that if it matches to a category it will pick a random word from that category.

Comment: Try `zorluk_secimi == "kolay"`. You want to compare your input to a _string_.

Comment: `kolay`,  `orta` and `zor` are not defined. you probably wants to compare with strings? like `if zorluk_secimi == 'kolay' :`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing:

```
  zorluk_secimi == kolay
  zorluk_secimi  == orta
  zorluk_secimi == zor
```

respectively to:

```
  zorluk_secimi == 'kolay'
  zorluk_secimi  == 'orta'
  zorluk_secimi == 'zor'
```